# To find recently updated date columns in database along with table name and value

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to get a column name those is get updated recently.
In some database some tables was there.

In some tables column dtattype like date, datetime, any date type
in that database some columns of above date columns were updated.

Here my question is to get list of table names and column name and value of those who are updated recently

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Are you trying to find records that have recently been updated?

Comment: yes i'm trying for those records updated recently

Comment: SQL Server doesn't track changes to data by default.  This can be enabled following the instructions for your version (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933994(v=sql.105).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

We have Triggers in SQL Server have a look at the advantages and disadvantages i hope it clarifies your doubt.[Triggers](http://www.moreprocess.com/database/sql/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-triggers-in-sql)

Comment: yah. we can use triggers for future purpose my need is to get updated column data  has done in past the column datatype is date and that should be less than current date

Answer (score 0):

You can try to:

a) decode DBCC LOG/fn_dblog() output by hand. Starting point: http://sqlfascination.com/2010/02/03/how-do-you-decode-a-simple-entry-in-the-transaction-log-part-1/

b) purchase "SysTools SQL Log Analyzer" or "ApexSQL Log"

What you want is possible but costs time or money.